# Transforming array of objects based upon key - javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am trying to figure out the most efficient method for reducing an array of objects based upon a unique key (key/values are dynamically returned in this case). I've tried to a combination of different methods using `concat`, `map`, or `filter` but haven't had much luck.

Original array of objects:

```
[
  {
    key: "Name",
    value: "John"
  },
  {
    key: "Company",
    value: "Acme"
  },
  {
    key: "Name",
    value: "Jack"
  },
  {
    key: "Name",
    value: "Matt"
  },
  {
    key: "Last",
    value: "Test"
  }
]
```

Desired Array:

```
[
  {
    key: "Name",
    values: [
      "John",
      "Jack",
      "Matt"
    ]
  },
  {
    key: "Company",
    values: [
      "Acme"
    ]
  },
  {
    key: "Last",
    values: [
      "Test"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You should add the code you've attempted to your question.

Comment: What would happens if you have the same `key` with the same `value`? For example, if you have multiple times a `{
    key: "Name",
    value: "Jack"
  },` …? Should you have the value "Jack" multiple times in the `values` or just once?

Comment: @ZER0-Ideally I would want to remove all duplicate values returned for the same key in the final array/object - This is a possibility that could arise

Answer (score 1):

Prob other ways, but a simple for loop would suffice:

```js
const data = [{
    key: "Name",
    value: "John"
  },
  {
    key: "Company",
    value: "Acme"
  },
  {
    key: "Name",
    value: "Jack"
  },
  {
    key: "Name",
    value: "Matt"
  },
  {
    key: "Last",
    value: "Test"
  }
]

let result = {}

for (const i in data) {
  result[data[i].key] = {
    key: data[i].key,
    values: [
      ...result[data[i].key] ? result[data[i].key].values : [],
      data[i].value
    ]
  }
}

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build a new object using `name` as the keys, and then use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to create the output you need from the object:

```js
const data = [
  { key: "Name", value: "John" },
  { key: "Company", value: "Acme" },
  { key: "Name", value: "Jack" },
  { key: "Name", value: "Matt" },
  { key: "Last", value: "Test" }
];

const out = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, { key, value }) => {

  // If the key doesn't exist on the object, add it
  // and initialise the value object
  acc[key] = acc[key] || { key, values: [] };

  // Push the value from the current iteration
  // into the values array
  acc[key].values.push(value);

  // Return the accumulator for the next iteration
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Is there a way to also check if an existing key doesn't include an existing value when pushing to the new object (if a duplicate value arises)? For example if `Name` also included another value of `John` - there would be 2 of the same value inserted into the accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

I think [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is the best solution here :)

```js
const initialArray = [
  {
    key: "Name",
    value: "John"
  },
  {
    key: "Company",
    value: "Acme"
  },
  {
    key: "Name",
    value: "Jack"
  },
  {
    key: "Name",
    value: "Matt"
  },
  {
    key: "Last",
    value: "Test"
  }
];

const result = initialArray.reduce((acc, obj) => {
   /* try to find object in the result array
      returns index or -1 if object is missing
   */
   const existingIndex = acc.findIndex(item => item.key === obj.key);

   if (existingIndex > -1) {
      /* object already exists, update its values array */
      acc[existingIndex].values.push(obj.value);
      return acc;
   } else {
     /* the key is first encountered, create an object in the result array */
     acc.push({
       key: obj.key,
       values: [obj.value],
     });
     return acc;
   }
}, []); // [] - default value is an empty array

console.log(result);
```